# How to get the updated count of rows in a table after changing the page number

Tags: selenium

Actually in the table i'm working on there is pagination. I could get the count of rows present in the first page.

When i change the page number, table row count is not getting updated as per the second page.

How to force selenium to update the count after changing the page number. page refresh is not the solution as i need to navigate to second page again

```
public Boolean checkMessageIsFailed(String message, String channelNameToCheck, String channelTypeToCheck) {

        UIPublish uiPublish = new UIPublish(driver);

        Boolean isMessageSent = null;

        SimplifyUtils.waitTillElementFound(uiPublish.currentPageNumber, 60);

        //getting the page count
        int pageCount = Integer.parseInt( uiPublish.totalPages.getText());

        for (int j=1; j< pageCount;pageCount++)
        {
            //getting the rows present in the table
            int messagesCount = uiPublish.listOfTextInMessages.size(); 

            for (int i = 0; i < messagesCount; i++) 
            {

                //getting the text from each row to match
                //matching the text of the required message sent with the messages present in the sent messages

                if (uiPublish.listOfTextInMessages.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase(message)) 
                {
                    String currentChannel = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='inbox-wrapper']//tr["+ (i + 1)+ "]")).get(i).getAttribute("data-original-title");

                }
            }
            //navigating to naxt page if the condition is not matched
            uiPublish.navigateToNextPage.click();
        }
        return isMessageSent;   
    }
```

[image: Page number for the table]

```html
<div class="grid simple">
  <div class="grid-body no-border email-body">
    <br>
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div id="email-list" class="table-responsive">
        <form id="schMsgFORM" name="schMsgFORM" action="/viewSentSchMessage.action"
              method="post">
          <table class="table  table-striped table-hover" id="emails">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>
                </th>
                <th>Social Channel
                </th>
                <th>Message
                </th>
                <th>Scheduled Time
                </th>
                <th>Actions
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr id="outputWTFrUjUyYlE1d1piNG1XUmNuUFBnUT09">
                <td class="small-cell v-align-middle" style="width: 2%">
                  <div class="checkbox check-success ">
                    <input name="msgcheckbox" id="chkboxWTFrUjUyYlE1d1piNG1XUmNuUFBnUT09"
                           value="WTFrUjUyYlE1d1piNG1XUmNuUFBnUT09" type="checkbox">
                    <label for="chkboxWTFrUjUyYlE1d1piNG1XUmNuUFBnUT09"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 150px">
                  <div class="account-sent">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="display-inline">
                        <div class="profile-pic" data-toggle="tooltip" title=""
                             data-original-title="galloway360">
                          <img class="account-profile"
                               src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000473105984/b0ad2b50b4fb81303d32720afea274ea_normal.png"
                               alt="">
                          <div class="social-icon-pub">
                            <span
                                  class="social-icon-twitter img-responsive social-icon-box">
                            </span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 50%">
                  <div class="muted message-wrap">
                    <br>
                    Source: Auto 2016/12/08 17:35:30 Message: How's your day?
                  </div>
                  <p class="sch-details">
                    Sent by: Nagarjuna reddy
                    <em>Scheduled from Profile :
                      NA
                    </em>
                  </p>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 15%">
                  <p class="muted m-t-5">
                    2016-12-08 05:35 PM
                  </p>
                  <p class="region">
                    (Asia/Calcutta)
                  </p>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 10%">
                  <a
                     href="/social/editUpdate?s360securetoken=SU0wxc4jrR8DE8Lf5hzKnRYasjg&amp;schMsgId=WTFrUjUyYlE1d1piNG1XUmNuUFBnUT09&amp;pageSource=publish"
                     data-toggle="tooltip" title="" type="button"
                     class="btn btn-success btn-small" data-original-title="Edit">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil">
                    </i>
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Selenium doesn't update anything, it just read from the html.

Comment: And please format the html to readable form.

Comment: @Guy i mean how to force selenium to update the table content by saying to read again.

Comment: Selenium can't update the table content. It can only read the data from the table.

Comment: How are you reading or storing  the table data in the first place? Can you add that code also? Are you firing a direct query to get all elements? Using page objects @Findby?

Comment: @Grasshopper getting elements present in one page in one go. given the code above

Comment: You need to send the findElements command again for uiPublish.listOfTextInMessages list to get updated count

Comment: @Grasshopper when there are two pages, count should get updated before second `for` loop. Variable `messagesCount` should update this ideally

Comment: Then you have a problem with the code that is updating the list on pagination. messagesCount is just reading the size and not updating anything. It is just a counter for the second for loop

Comment: @Grasshopper actually i'm trying to navigate to next page and then again read the table count. Some times i'm getting `org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: The element reference is stale.` exception

Comment: Just use the findElements command again when you paginate to update your list and you should not get this exception.